# Crashplan and regex - excluding files based on filename

Tags: regex

Crashplan allows for excluding files from a backup set by using regex for the exclusion criteria (there is no inclusion criteria functionality). For my particular use case I have a folder that contains these files:

```
C_VOL-b001.spf
C_VOL-b001-i001.md5
C_VOL-b001-i001.spi
E_VOL-b001.spf
E_VOL-b001-i001.md5
E_VOL-b001-i001.spi
F_VOL-b001.spf
F_VOL-b001-i001.md5
F_VOL-b001-i001.spi
G_VOL-b001.spf
G_VOL-b001-i001.md5
G_VOL-b001-i001.spi
```

and I want to exclude any file that doesn't begin with the C_VOL filename. These are backup files from another backup software, Shadowprotect, but I only want to include the C volume files and exclude the others. The incremental files will continue to be added to each of the volume sets using the naming schema of -i001, -i002, etc.

So far I've tried the following:

```
^E_VOL
^E_VOL.*
```

and a few other variations, with no success. I'm not sure if Crashplan only allows for selecting based on the filetype extension (their regex examples are here http://goo.gl/qDAEcR ). They do mention that "Note that CrashPlan treats all file separators as forward slashes (/)."

I'm not sure if Crashplan recognizes all regex expressions. If it helps, back in 2008 I emailed their tech support with a regex question and one of the founders of Crashplan, Matt Dornquast, helped me with a the following regex:

I am trying to exclude any file that either:

```
1.       have an extension of .spf, or
2.       has a file name of the type, XXXXXX-cd.spi
3.       But also allow for backup of files with the name type of, xxxxx.spi
```

And his regex worked perfectly:

```
(?i).+(?:\-cd\.spi|\.spf)$
```

I've contacted their tech support again but they said they will no longer help with regex questions.

Comment: So, basically, you want a regex that matches all file names that start with `C_VOL` in order to exclude them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you could use the following regex:

```
.*/C_VOL.*
```

I created this based on [this example (link)](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Configuring/Excluding_Files_By_Using_File_Type_And_Regular_Expressions#Example_2_-_Exclude_Folders_Starting_With_TEMP) they featured on the website you linked in your question. Please let us know if it's working :)